# Doctrine not generating cross-database foreign key constraints in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine-orm

I have two tables, db1.Contact and db2.Recipient. Every recipient should be a contact so I have a foreign key set up between the two tables on the db1.Contact.ContactID field.

I represent this in Recipient.php with the following annotation:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="\db1\Contact")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="ContactID", referencedColumnName="ContactID")
 **/
private $Contact;
```

I shouldn't need any code in the Contact.php for this.

When I generate the database (using doctrine orm:schema-tool:create --dump-sql) I can see that the Recipient.ContactID field is created and given an index. However, no query is generated and executed to create the foreign key constraint. So to be clear, I don't get any errors but the constraint is never generated.

How can I resolve this? Surely doctrine supports cross-database foreign keys? I've checked out the annotation documentation and looked to see if there are any options for the create tool but I can't see any way to turn this functionality on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a workaround for this that I explain [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30193861/doctrine-doesnt-generate-cross-database-foreign-keys/30195848#30195848). Essentially, Doctrine strips cross-database foreign keys by default because not all database systems support it, but you can disable it by commenting out some code in the Doctrine library.

Answer (score 0):

Your `ManyToOne` association seems wrong. You should use the [FQCN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fully_qualified_name#Programming) of the entities if your codebase is namespaced (or just classname if entities of both side located in same directory), **not table names**.

For example

```
/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="YourNamespace\Entities\Contact")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="ContactID", referencedColumnName="ContactID")
 **/
private $contact;
```

You may want to read more about association mapping [here](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html).

Comment: The association is fine, as well as that representing my database/table structure is also represents the namespaces. So I have a Contact entity in the db1 namespace and a Recipient entity in the db2 namespace. If this was completely wrong then the db creation tool would not work at all.

Answer (score 0):

Doctrine doesn't support cross-DB FK:

> In Doctrine, joining data across databases is not technically
>   “supported” by a designed feature, but you can make it work by
>   tricking Doctrine a little bit.

Source: http://www.doctrine-project.org/2009/06/19/cross-database-joins.html

Comment: That post is from 2009 and there's a frustrated guy in the comments from a few months ago asking them to remove old blog posts so I wouldn't say that this answer is valid anymore.